# Exhaustive properties in Haskell QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Consider the following QuickCheck program in Haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.All

prop_trivial :: Bool
prop_trivial = 42 == (6 * 7)

-- Wacky boilerplate to make all tests run.
return []
runTests = $quickCheckAll
main = do
  runTests
```

This works with ghc version 7.8.3 and QuickCheck 2.7.6. Problem is that it repeats the test 100 times. I look around for a mitigation and find `exhaustive` in [the QuickCheck docs here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Property). Groovy!  I change my `prop_trivial` to the following:

```
prop_trivial = exhaustive $ property $ 42 == (6 * 7)
```

which type-checks and compiles, but fails:

```
=== prop_trivial from /blahblahblah/FooTest.hs:6 ===
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 1 test): 
False
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to understand and debug this result; the docs are a bit too thin for me to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can use `once` to modify a property to run only once.

Some example code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.All

prop_trivial :: Int -> Bool
prop_trivial x = x == x
prop_trivial2 = once prop_trivial
prop_true = True
prop_true2 = once True

-- Wacky boilerplate to make all tests run.
return []
runTests = $quickCheckAll
main = do
  putStrLn $ "exhaustive prop_trivial  = " ++ show (exhaustive prop_trivial)
  putStrLn $ "exhaustive prop_trivial2 = " ++ show (exhaustive prop_trivial2)
  putStrLn $ "exhaustive prop_true     = " ++ show (exhaustive prop_true)
  putStrLn $ "exhaustive prop_true2    = " ++ show (exhaustive prop_true2)
  runTests
```

Output:

```
exhaustive prop_trivial  = False
exhaustive prop_trivial2 = False
exhaustive prop_true     = True
exhaustive prop_true2    = False
=== prop_trivial from qc2.hs:5 ===
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.

=== prop_trivial2 from qc2.hs:7 ===
+++ OK, passed 1 tests.

=== prop_true from qc2.hs:8 ===
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.

=== prop_true2 from qc2.hs:9 ===
+++ OK, passed 1 tests.
```

`exhaustive` *prop* only returns True if testing of *prop* is known to be exhaustive - note the difference between `exhaustive True` and `exhaustive $ once True`.

Answer (score 3):

You might like [smallcheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/smallcheck). It is not as developed as QuickCheck, but quite nice for exhaustive testing. Where QuickCheck generates random inputs, smallcheck generates its inputs systematically, running your properties on all inputs up to a given (by you) size. For types with finitely many inhabitants, this makes it pretty trivial to set up exhaustive tests, and because we're not trying to generate random stuff, it also makes it easy to avoid repeating tests. Here's a simple ghci example:

```
Test.SmallCheck> smallCheck 10 (6*7 == 42)
Completed 1 tests without failure.
```

The `10` is a maximum depth used to choose when to stop generating inputs; since there are no inputs, it's ignored in this example. For an example where the size is used, consider:

```
Test.SmallCheck> smallCheck 10 (\x -> x <= (10 :: Integer))
Completed 21 tests without failure.
Test.SmallCheck> smallCheck 20 (\x -> x <= (10 :: Integer))
Failed test no. 22.
there exists 11 such that
  condition is false
```

Answer (score 0):

The [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#exhaustive) is really straight-forward.  The default definition for `exhaustive` is used for the `Property` instance and the default is `exhaustive _ = False`.  I think you probably want `exhaustive $ 42 == (6 * 7)`

Comment: Sadly, with `exhaustive $ 42 == (6 * 7)`, the test still runs 100 times. I was trying to get a `Property Bool` instance for exhaustive and obviously didn't quite make it.